# How to append an element to a textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textblock element:

```
<TextBlock name="txt">bla bla<TextBlock>
```

Then I programatically create another textblock:

```
var block = new TextBlock(){Text = "test", Foreground = Brushes.Red};
```

How do append I the block textblock at the end of the txt textblock?

```
txt += block; //Doesn't work
txt.Inlines.add(block); //This also doesn't work
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a line to a textblock programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542705/adding-a-line-to-a-textblock-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to Text property:

```
txt.Text += block.Text;
```

---

Create StackPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal and add texBlock as children in it.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="bla bla"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and in code:

```
stackPanel.Children.Add(block);
```

Comment: I need to add the entire textblock there because I want to keep the color of the text.

Comment: Then why dont you appened `txt.Text` to `block.Text`?

Comment: I need to append many different textblocks to the txt textblock, and they all have different color and various formating.

Comment: @user3595338 - See the update in answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TextBlock.Text` property:

```
txt.Text += block.Text;
```